# R: Extending function to other (S3) classes

Tags: r, oop

**EDIT:** The question has changed slightly to why a *specific* extension doesn't work, rather than why a general method doesn't work.

As indicated by the title, I'm having trouble extending functions to other (S3) classes.

For example:

```
x <- y <- runif(10)
loessModel = loess(y ~ x)

methods("cor")
## [1] cor.test cor.test.default* cor.test.formula*

cor.loess = function(loessModel, ...) { cor(loessModel$x, loessModel$y, ...) }
cor(loessModel)
## Error in cor(loessModel) : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
```

However, the following works:

```
getCor = function(x, y, ...) { UseMethod("getCor") }
getCor.default = function(x, y, ...) { cor(x, y, ...) }
getCor.loess = function(loessModel, ...) getCor(loessModel$x, loessModel$y, ...)
getCor(loessModel)
## [,1]
## x    1
```

So... as explained by Josh, the first method of extending `cor` didn't work because `cor` isn't a generic function. The second method works, but I can't extend it to a class of `LoessList`. This is puzzling to me, particularly as it works 'outside the function':

```
set.seed(13)
df = data.frame(id = rep.int(1:2, 10), 
                x = runif(20), 
                y = runif(20))

loessList = structure(dlply(df, "id", loess, formula = as.formula("y ~ x")),
                      class = "LoessList")

getCor.LoessList = function(loessList, ...) { ldply(loessList, getCor, ...) }
getCor(loessList)
## Error in is.data.frame(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

ldply(loessList, getCor)
##   id           1
## 1  1 -0.01552707
## 2  2 -0.38997723
```

*On a more general note, are there any good guides to OOP in R? I have been using http://logic.sysbiol.cam.ac.uk/teaching/advancedR/slides.pdf as my main point of reference, but other sources are always appreciated.*

Cheers

Comment: `cor` doesn't appear to be a generic function by default.  When  you called `methods("cor")` notice that you were getting results for `cor.test`.  Since `cor` isn't a generic function it doesn't know it should dispatch the call to your `cor.loess`.

Comment: On OOP in R, try `https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/SoftwareSystems`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Generics in S3 can be extended but if you want to turn a non-generic into a generic and extend it then you will need S4.  Here we define an S4 generic which defaults to `stats::cor`.  Then we make the S3 method `loess` available to S4 and define a `loess` method:

```
setGeneric("cor", function(x, ...) stats::cor(x, ...))
setOldClass("loess") # let S4 use an S3 class
setMethod("cor", list(x = "loess"), 
   def = function(x, ...) callNextMethod(x$x, x$y, ...))
```

Now we can do this:

```
example(loess)
cor(cars.lo)
```

**2.** The other approach if you want to stick with S3 is to clobber `cor` with your own S3 generic:

```
cor <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("cor")
cor.default <- stats::cor
cor.loess <- function(x, ...) stats::cor(x$x, x$y, ...)

example(loess)
cor(cars.lo)
```

**3.** Of course you could just redefine `cor` appropriately and forget about OO dispatch.   There are actually some potential problems with this since it makes `cor` the parent frame of call to the function doing the real work but in many cases it won't matter.  (See `lm` source code to find out how to circumvent this.)

```
cor <- function(x, ...) {
    if (inherits(x, "loess")) return(cor(x$x, x$y, ...))
    stats::cor(x, ...)
}
```

**Info:** For info on S3 see `?UseMethod` and references and links on that page.  For info on S4 see `?Methods` and references and links on that page.

UPDATE: Added additional approaches and references.

Comment: Thanks. Josh and agstudy's comments were informative and useful - your answer comes closest to answering my first question. I added a second bit - sorry about this but I thought the two were related enough. If you could indicate what the problem is here, I will gladly except your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to the warning when you run `methods(cor)`.

```
R> methods("cor")
[1] cor.test          cor.test.default* cor.test.formula*

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
Warning message:
In methods("cor") : function 'cor' appears not to be generic
```

`cor` isn't generic, so you can't just define a method.  You'd need to define a generic too, which is what you did in the solution in your question.

Comment: Ah, thank you sir. I don't get this warning message, do you know how I can 'turn it on'?

Comment: @user32259 amazing, you should set `options(warn=0)`